# Basic mail sending : SSL authentication error

Tags: c#, .net, sendmail

I am using Unity5 and writing some code to send a basic mail.
I've read documentation as well as other users' problems, but can't seem to get my code to work properly.
When I try to send the mail get this error :
 "InvalidOperationException: SSL authentication error: RemoteCertificateNotAvailable, RemoteCertificateChainErrors"

Here is my code so far, hope you guys got any advice ! :) Thanks.

```
var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
        Credentials = (ICredentialsByHost)new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyMail", "MyPWD"),
        EnableSsl = true
    };

    client.Send("MyMail", "MyPWD", "test", "testbody");
```

Comment: Did you enable SMTP in your gmail account? I know that GMail has very specific requirements for third-parties to be able to send email via it.

Comment: Have you tried installing the remote certificate? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148019/authentication-or-decryption-has-failed-when-sending-mail-to-gmail-using-ssl

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.  I'd check your account if this doesn't work.

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password")
            };

            smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: Does not work for me, and I don't know what to look for in my account

Answer (score 0):

Based upon this [Google SMTP settings page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) the ports are:

> Port 465 (SSL required)
>   Port 587 (TLS required)

So you want port 465 for SSL

Comment: Made Unity crash instantly : /

Comment: Setting a different port in your SmtpClient made Unity crash? That *sounds* more like a Unity problem than a .Net issue. Do you have any more details, like an error message or your machine ran out of memory? If you wrap your code snippet in a try{}catch{} and debug can you see a trapped error before it crashes (or prevent the crash?). As an alternative you could try testing your SMTP code in VisualStudio in a unit test project to make sure that is fine before seeing if the Unity editor can handle running it.

Comment: Is it possible your virus protection software is aggressively preventing unsigned applications from attempting to send emails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702453/smtpclient-send-crashes-production-application